# From which point near the NSW/QLD border does it become legal for pedestrians to walk along the M1 (Pacific Highway)?

Tags: legal, australia, hitchhiking, queensland, new-south-wales

Two days ago I was hitchhiking back to Sydney from Queensland.

I'm sure it's legal to walk along the [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_1_(Australia)), [Pacific Highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Highway_(Australia)) on the NSW side since there were signs about bicycle crossings, no signs saying "no pedestrians" at the on-ramps, and a couple of police vehicles drove past me without stopping, some of which definitely made eye contact with me.

On the Queensland side there were definitely "no pedestrians" signs at the on-ramps.

[image: "Motorway Entrance" sign]

As it's quite tricky to get onto the Pacific Highway to hitchhike in Queensland it's good to know exactly where I need to get to before I can hitch directly on the highway.

I don't think it's right at the border but I may be wrong. It may have to do with whether a stretch is classed as "motorway" or "highway" etc or it may be a combination of that and which state the section is in.

It seemed that it was definitely OK to be walk along this road from [Chinderah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinderah,_New_South_Wales) heading south, but maybe I would've been fine getting on some distance further north.

Comment: Good question! It might be hard to get any sort of definitive answer here without someone local seeing it, but I'd _generally_ say you should be ok until you see those signs. Generically speaking, those signs will usually be in place on freeways/motorways but not highways.

Answer (score 7):

> From which point near the NSW/QLD border does it become legal for pedestrians to walk along the M1 (Pacific Highway)?

From which point do I change my clock?

Really you'd have to guess a bit, but I'd say you'd be okay once you've passed the 'Welcome to NSW' sign... Which coincidentally is not accessible by pedestrians from the QLD side on *the physical highway*.. and instead you'd have to go around Tweed Heads via the Gold Coast highway.

But it's a toss up. I'm a resident driven this route a hundred times.

Comment: Are pedestrians actually allowed on motorways in NSW? I couldn't find much online to say they're not, except perhaps for this story mentioning a $2200 fine for wandering on Sydney's motorways: http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/news/nsw/pedestrians-gamble-with-death-as-they-take-motorway-shortcuts/news-story/4f87e5416d3962cf385c7e6499c4440b - "Pedestrians are prohibited from walking on motorways and can face a fine of $2200." The absence of a sign doesn't make it legal - in the UK, motorway entrances often don't explicitly say "no pedestrians"

Comment: I don't walk along NSW highways/motorways and hence was just going off the given information/assumed information.